# ReadProcessMemory Win32

Tags: winapi, readprocessmemory

```
ReadProcessMemory(hProc,(LPCVOID)(7845CDDC),&PHP,4,NULL);
```

When I enter that i get this error in Dev-C++ Win32 :

> C:\Dev-Cpp\main.cpp invalid suffix "CDDC" on integer constant

any idea why?

Comment: You probably want a hex constant, that is to say `0x7845CDDC`

Comment: thank you, just had to add 0x :)

Comment: @Cicada: you should post your comment as an answer so you can get points for it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I would, but since the OP hasn't accepted any of his previous questions, why bother? :) Oh well let's repwhore anyway!

Comment: Please update your IDE to the following version, which fixes an immense list of bugs, ships with GCC 4.6.1 or 4.7.0, and is fully portable: http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want a hex constant, that is to say `0x7845CDDC`.

> ReadProcessMemory(hProc,(LPCVOID)(0x7845CDDC),&PHP,4,NULL);

Answer (score -1):

**[ReadProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory)** should have the **lpBaseAddress** parameter as a pointer to the base address in the specified process from which to read. 
The problem with "7845CDDC" is that it is a Hex value (should be 0x7845CDDC), but you can enter the value as an Decimal as well (will be 2017840604).

So you can call:

```
ReadProcessMemory(hProc,(LPCVOID)(2017840604),&PHP,4,NULL);
```